# Create parent child relation JSON tree

Tags: php

This is my code I have three table posts table, comments table, and likes table. I have a left joined all three tables with postid common in all three tables. I'm getting all data perfectly but I'm getting repeating data of postdata (ex: Postid=1) I don't want that. My problem is getting repeating data of Postdata (ex: Postid=1) I want to make a parent of Postdata where postsdata=1 and I want to insert all data into parent

```
<?php
    include "../dcon.php";
    $sql = "select * FROM posts left join comments on comments.Cpostid=posts.PostId left join likes on likes.postid=posts.PostId";


        $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);  
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        $menus=array();


     for($i=0; $i<$result; $i++){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     foreach($row as $index => $row ){
        $menus[]=[
        'PostId'=>$row['PostId'],
        'PostVideo'=>$row['PostVideo'],
        'PostDesc'=>$row['PostDesc'],
        'PostImage'=>$row['PostImage'],
        'PostedBy'=>$row['PostedBy'],
        'UserName'=>$row['UserName'],
        'Status'=>$row['Status'],
        'PostParent'=>$row['PostParent'],
        'likes'=>$row['likes'],
        'comments'=>[
        $index => [
        'commentsid'=>$row['commentsId'],
        'comments'=>$row['comments'],
        'Cpostid'=>$row['Cpostid'],
        'time'=>$row['time'],
        ],],
        
        'likes'=>[
        $index =>[
        'Likeid'=>$row['Lid'],
        'dislikes'=>$row['dislikes'],
        'postid'=>$row['postid'],
        'userid'=>$row['userid'],
]]
];
        }
     }  
     echo json_encode($menus,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

My output was below:

```
[
    {
        "PostId": "1",
        "PostVideo": "v2.mp4",
        "PostDesc": "this is a tutorial on bench press",
        "PostImage": "null",
        "PostedBy": "Irfan khan",
        "UserName": "irfan",
        "Status": "1",
        "PostParent": null,
        "likes": {
            "Likeid": "1",
            "dislikes": "0",
            "postid": "1",
            "userid": "1"
        },
        "comments": {
            "commentsid": "1",
            "comments": "awesome video",
            "Cpostid": "1",
            "time": "2020-12-16 17:33:33"
        }
    },
    {
        "PostId": "1",
        "PostVideo": "v2.mp4",
        "PostDesc": "this is a tutorial on bench press",
        "PostImage": "null",
        "PostedBy": "Irfan khan",
        "UserName": "khan",
        "Status": "1",
        "PostParent": null,
        "likes": {
            "Likeid": "1",
            "dislikes": "0",
            "postid": "1",
            "userid": "1"
        },
        "comments": {
            "commentsid": "2",
            "comments": "good workouts",
            "Cpostid": "1",
            "time": "2020-12-16 17:33:33"
        }
    },
    {
        "PostId": "1",
        "PostVideo": "v1.mp4",
        "PostDesc": "Chicken generally includes low fat in the meat itself (castrated roosters excluded). The fat is highly concentrated on the skin. A 100g serving of baked chicken breast contains 4 grams of fat and 31 grams of protein, compared to 10 grams of fat and 27 grams of protein for the same portion of broiled, lean skirt steak.",
        "PostImage": "im1",
        "PostedBy": "Rehmat",
        "UserName": null,
        "Status": "1",
        "PostParent": null,
        "likes": {
            "Likeid": "20",
            "dislikes": "0",
            "postid": "1",
            "userid": "4"
        },
        "comments": {
            "commentsid": null,
            "comments": null,
            "Cpostid": null,
            "time": null
        }
    },
    {
        "PostId": "1",
        "PostVideo": "v1.mp4",
        "PostDesc": "Chicken generally includes low fat in the meat itself (castrated roosters excluded). The fat is highly concentrated on the skin. A 100g serving of baked chicken breast contains 4 grams of fat and 31 grams of protein, compared to 10 grams of fat and 27 grams of protein for the same portion of broiled, lean skirt steak.",
        "PostImage": "im1",
        "PostedBy": "Rehmat",
        "UserName": null,
        "Status": "1",
        "PostParent": null,
        "likes": {
            "Likeid": "26",
            "dislikes": "0",
            "postid": "1",
            "userid": "4"
        },
        "comments": {
            "commentsid": null,
            "comments": null,
            "Cpostid": null,
            "time": null
        }
    },
    {
        "PostId": "3",
        "PostVideo": null,
        "PostDesc": "this is an image of chicken",
        "PostImage": "post.jpg",
        "PostedBy": "khan",
        "UserName": null,
        "Status": "0",
        "PostParent": null,
        "likes": {
            "Likeid": null,
            "dislikes": null,
            "postid": null,
            "userid": null
        },
        "comments": {
            "commentsid": null,
            "comments": null,
            "Cpostid": null,
            "time": null
        }
    },
    {
        "PostId": "9",
        "PostVideo": null,
        "PostDesc": "gdhgh",
        "PostImage": "ghghdf",
        "PostedBy": null,
        "UserName": null,
        "Status": null,
        "PostParent": null,
        "likes": {
            "Likeid": null,
            "dislikes": null,
            "postid": null,
            "userid": null
        },
        "comments": {
            "commentsid": null,
            "comments": null,
            "Cpostid": null,
            "time": null
        }
    }
];
```

I want my output like below:

```
{
            "PostId": "1",
            "PostVideo": "v2.mp4",
            "PostDesc": "this is a tutorial on bench press",
            "PostImage": "null",
            "PostedBy": "Irfan khan",
            "UserName": "irfan",
            "Status": "1",
            "PostParent": null,
            "likes": 
                '0':{
                "Likeid": "1",
                "dislikes": "0",
                "postid": "1",
                "userid": "1"
            }, 
                '1':{
                "Likeid": "1",
                "dislikes": "0",
                "postid": "1",
                "userid": "1"
            }, 
                '2':{
                "Likeid": "1",
                "dislikes": "0",
                "postid": "1",
                "userid": "1"
            }, 
                '3':{
                "Likeid": "1",
                "dislikes": "0",
                "postid": "1",
                "userid": "1"
            },
            "comments": 
               '0':{
                "commentsid": "1",
                "comments": "awesome video",
                "Cpostid": "1",
                "time": "2020-12-16 17:33:33"
            },
               '1':{
                "commentsid": "1",
                "comments": "awesome video",
                "Cpostid": "1",
                "time": "2020-12-16 17:33:33"
            },
               '2':{
                "commentsid": "1",
                "comments": "awesome video",
                "Cpostid": "1",
                "time": "2020-12-16 17:33:33"
            },
               '3':{
                "commentsid": "1",
                "comments": "awesome video",
                "Cpostid": "1",
                "time": "2020-12-16 17:33:33"
            }
        },
 {
            "PostId": "9",
            "PostVideo": null,
            "PostDesc": "gdhgh",
            "PostImage": "ghghdf",
            "PostedBy": null,
            "UserName": null,
            "Status": null,
            "PostParent": null,
            "likes": {
                "Likeid": null,
                "dislikes": null,
                "postid": null,
                "userid": null
            },
            "comments": {
                "commentsid": null,
                "comments": null,
                "Cpostid": null,
                "time": null
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... At first I thought that your loops were the problem, and you misunderstood the behavior. But then I saw your "***i want my output like below***", and that didn't made sense, specifically you wanting duplicate likes/comments.

First, the loops: a `for` loop and an inner `foreach` loop. The `for` loop iterates over the number of results. The inner `foreach` loop iterates over all the results. So if we have 6 results, instead of only iterating 6 times, we iterate 36 times (6 result count x 6 results).

We actually need only 1 loop:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$menus = [];
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
    $menus[] = [
        ...
    ];
}
```

Next, we avoid duplicate posts by indexing the `$menus` with `PostId`. If the `PostId` does not yet exist in `$menus`, we insert the post; otherwise we just append the like/comment:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$menus = [];
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (!isset($menus[$row['PostId']])) {
        $menus[$row['PostId']] = [
            'PostId' => $row['PostId'],
            ...
            'comments' => [],
            'likes' => [],
        ];
    }

    $menus[$row['PostId']]['comments'][] = [
        ...
    ];
    $menus[$row['PostId']]['likes'][] = [
        ...
    ];
}
```

If for some reason you don't want the `$menus` indexed by `PostId`, we can just call `array_values()` after the loop to re-index it with zero-based sequential integer:

```
foreach (...) { ... }
$menus = array_values($menus);
```

As for the duplicate `likes`/`comments`, you were explicit about it. But just in case you actually want non-duplicate, we can also index them by their `Likeid` and `commentsid`, and insert/ignore as necessary:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$menus = [];
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (!isset($menus[$row['PostId']])) {
        $menus[$row['PostId']] = [
            'PostId' => $row['PostId'],
            ...
            'comments' => [],
            'likes' => [],
        ];
    }

    if (!isset($menus[$row['PostId']]['comments'][$row['commentsid']])) {
        $menus[$row['PostId']]['comments'][$row['commentsid']] = [
            ...
        ];
    }

    if (!isset($menus[$row['PostId']]['Likes'][$row['Lid']])) {
        $menus[$row['PostId']]['Likes'][$row['Lid']] = [
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```

And if we also don't want the `comments`/`likes` indexed by `commentsid`/`Lid`, we can call `array_values()` on them as well:

```
foreach (...) { ... }
$menus = array_values($menus);
foreach ($menus as &$menu) {
    $menu['comments'] = array_values($menu['comments']);
    $menu['likes'] = array_values($menu['likes']);
}
unset($menu);
// Or
array_walk($menus, function (&$menu) {
    $menu['comments'] = array_values($menu['comments']);
    $menu['likes'] = array_values($menu['likes']);
});
```

Comment: @irfan nw. please accept as answer. thanks.